# How to read JSONP response data in name and value pairs in Jquery ajax.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am trying to read JSON file from other domain with JSONP technique

Here is the JSON

```
callback({
  "response":{"docs":[
      {
        "FirstName":"qwe",
        "LastName":"asd",
        "Age":"30"},
      {
        "FirstName":"zxc",
        "LastName":"bnm",
        "Age":"40"},

        .
        .
        .
      {
        "FirstName":"poi",
        "LastName":"lkj",
        "Age":"20"},
      ]},
})
```

Here is the Jquery code

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://qqq.com/",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (msg) {
                         $.each(msg.response.docs, function (key, value){
                              alert(key +"is"+value);
                    }
         });
```

From the above code i am expecting to get the alert output as

```
FirstName is qwe
LastName is asd 
and so on
```

But i am getting the alert as

```
0 is [object Object]
1 is [object Object]
and so on
```

can i know what i need to do to get the out put as my expectation like

```
FirstName is qwe
LastName is asd
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: the `value` in your `each()` callback points towards one object in the array. If you want it's contents, you have to reference those, eg., by using another for loop inside the `each()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$each` function is iterating over the `docs` array. The parameters passed to it will be:

- `key`: index of doc object
- `val`: the doc object itself

Instead, you probably want to also iterate over every (key, value) pair with another loop:

```
success: function (msg) {
  $.each(msg.response.docs, function (index, doc){
      $.each(doc, function (key, val) {
        console.log(key + 'is' + val);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: r u sure that key will return the key instead of index like 0  1  2

Comment: Yes, according to the [jQuery docs for $each on objects](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

You should first iterate an array and then iterate in single object:

Something like this:

```
success: function (msg) {
    $.each(msg.response.docs, function (singleDoc){
        $.each(singleDoc, function (key, value){
            alert(key +"is"+value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are using each method of jquery then you get the index as first parameter and in second parameter you get the each object in iterating order.

So you need to use code like this

```
  $.each(msg.response.docs, function (key,value){

      console.log('FirstName is '+value.FirstName);

      console.log('LastName is'+value.LastName); 
      .
      .
      .
    });
```